# How to verify if a URL has a GET parameter using a regex

Tags: ruby, regex, file, url

I have a file containing a bunch of random URLs:

```
https://google.com
http://fakesite.net/php?id=2
https://example.com/
http://anotherexample.com/pho?admin=2
```

How can I verify that the URL contains a GET parameter and not a POST using a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean whether it has query parameters?

```
require 'uri'

if URI('http://fakesite.net/php').query
  ...
end
```

If you insist on using a regexp use this

```
match = URI.regexp.match('http://fakesite.net/php?id=2')
if match[8]
  ...
end
```

You can print the regular expression with

```
puts URI.regexp
```

It is looooooong, you best just use the `URI` class.

Comment: `Using a regular expression`

Comment: What does the `match[8]` part do?

Comment: It gets the 8th capture group, which happens to be query part.